419 Status Error on Fetch POST Request in Laravel API
I'm working on a React frontend and Laravel backend to manage product data. When I try to send a POST request to my Laravel API using the fetch method, I keep getting a 419 status code in the response. I understand that this might be related to CSRF protection in Laravel, but I'm not sure how to resolve it for API calls.
const handleSubmit = (e) =\> {
e.preventDefault();

    const productData = {
        barcode: barcode,
        product_name: productName,
        description: description,
        stock: Number(stock),
        price: Number(price)
    };
    
    fetch('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/products', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(productData),
    })
    .then((response) => {
        if (!response.ok) {
            throw new Error('Network response was not ok');
        }
        return response.json();
    })
    .then((data) => {
        console.log('Success:', data);
    })
    .catch((error) => {
        console.error('Error:', error);
    });

};

I suspect it has something to do with the CSRF token, but I thought that Laravel APIs don’t require CSRF tokens. Is there a way to bypass this for API requests, or am I missing something else?

The easiest way to resolve this is to just pass the CSRF token instead of bypassing it.

so i'll be passing it in my blade.php? or directly in my handlesubmit

You'd pass it as a header, this article will explain multiple ways of passing the CSRF token with fetch() requests
